# VHDL Nonresolved Signal 'i2c_rx_data' has multiple sources

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am working to connect an FPGA to the MPU-6050 Gyro Sensor via I2C. I already tried different things but now i am getting the Error : Nonresolved Signal 'i2c_rx_data' has multiple sources (106)
Any Ideas what i am doing wrong?

Grettings Losspost

My Source Code:

```
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Project      : Invent a Chip
-- Authors      : 
-- Year         : 2016
-----------------------------------------------------------------

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.iac_pkg.all;

entity invent_a_chip is
    port (
        -- Global Signals
        clock               : in  std_ulogic;
        reset               : in  std_ulogic;
        -- global
        --reset_n           : in    std_ulogic;

        -- Interface Signals
        -- 7-Seg
        sevenseg_cs         : out std_ulogic;
        sevenseg_wr         : out std_ulogic;
        sevenseg_addr       : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_ADDR_SEVENSEG-1 downto 0);
        sevenseg_din        : in  std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_SEVENSEG-1 downto 0);
        sevenseg_dout       : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_SEVENSEG-1 downto 0);
        -- ADC/DAC
        adc_dac_cs          : out std_ulogic;
        adc_dac_wr          : out std_ulogic;
        adc_dac_addr        : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_ADDR_ADC_DAC-1 downto 0);
        adc_dac_din         : in  std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_ADC_DAC-1 downto 0);
        adc_dac_dout        : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_ADC_DAC-1 downto 0);
        -- AUDIO
        audio_cs            : out std_ulogic;
        audio_wr            : out std_ulogic;
        audio_addr          : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_ADDR_AUDIO-1 downto 0);
        audio_din           : in  std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_AUDIO-1 downto 0);
        audio_dout          : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_AUDIO-1 downto 0);
        audio_irq_left      : in  std_ulogic;
        audio_irq_right     : in  std_ulogic;
        audio_ack_left      : out std_ulogic;
        audio_ack_right     : out std_ulogic;
        -- Infra-red Receiver
        ir_cs               : out std_ulogic;
        ir_wr               : out std_ulogic;
        ir_addr             : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_ADDR_IR-1 downto 0);
        ir_din              : in  std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_IR-1 downto 0);
        ir_dout             : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_IR-1 downto 0);
        ir_irq_rx           : in  std_ulogic;
        ir_ack_rx           : out std_ulogic;
        -- LCD
        lcd_cs              : out std_ulogic;
        lcd_wr              : out std_ulogic;
        lcd_addr            : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_ADDR_LCD-1 downto 0);
        lcd_din             : in  std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_LCD-1 downto 0);
        lcd_dout            : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_LCD-1 downto 0);
        lcd_irq_rdy         : in  std_ulogic;
        lcd_ack_rdy         : out std_ulogic;
        -- SRAM
        sram_cs             : out std_ulogic;
        sram_wr             : out std_ulogic;
        sram_addr           : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_ADDR_SRAM-1 downto 0);
        sram_din            : in  std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_SRAM-1 downto 0);
        sram_dout           : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_SRAM-1 downto 0);
        -- UART
        uart_cs             : out std_ulogic;
        uart_wr             : out std_ulogic;
        uart_addr           : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_ADDR_UART-1 downto 0);
        uart_din            : in  std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_UART-1 downto 0);
        uart_dout           : out std_ulogic_vector(CW_DATA_UART-1 downto 0);
        uart_irq_rx         : in  std_ulogic;
        uart_irq_tx         : in  std_ulogic;
        uart_ack_rx         : out std_ulogic;
        uart_ack_tx         : out std_ulogic;
        -- GPIO
        gp_ctrl             : out std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);
        gp_in               : in  std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);
        gp_out              : out std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);
        -- LED/Switches/Keys
        led_green           : out std_ulogic_vector(8  downto 0);
        led_red             : out std_ulogic_vector(17 downto 0);
        switch              : in  std_ulogic_vector(17 downto 0);
        key                 : in  std_ulogic_vector(2  downto 0);
        -- I2C Protokoll
        i2c_sdat                : inout std_logic;
        i2c_sclk                : inout std_logic


        );
end invent_a_chip;

architecture rtl of invent_a_chip is

    -- connection signals to i2c master
    signal reset_n                  : std_logic;
    signal i2c_busy                 : std_ulogic;
    signal i2c_cs                   : std_ulogic;
    signal i2c_mode                 : std_ulogic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal i2c_slave_addr           : std_ulogic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal i2c_bytes_tx             : unsigned(4 downto 0);
    signal i2c_bytes_rx             : unsigned(4 downto 0);
    signal i2c_tx_data              : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal i2c_tx_data_valid        : std_ulogic;
    signal i2c_rx_data              : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal i2c_rx_data_valid        : std_ulogic;
    signal i2c_rx_data_en           : std_ulogic;
    signal i2c_error                : std_ulogic;

    type state_t is (S_INIT, I2C_CON, S_WAIT_TIME,I2C_READ);
    signal state, state_nxt : state_t;
    signal gyro                     : std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);


    component i2c_master is
        generic (
            GV_SYS_CLOCK_RATE       : natural := 50000000;
            GV_I2C_CLOCK_RATE       : natural := 400000;    -- standard mode: (100000) 100 kHz; fast mode: 400000 Hz (400 kHz)
            GW_SLAVE_ADDR           : natural := 7;
            GV_MAX_BYTES            : natural := 16;
            GB_USE_INOUT            : boolean := true;
            GB_TIMEOUT              : boolean := false
        );
        port (
            clock                   : in    std_ulogic;
            reset_n                 : in    std_ulogic;
            -- i2c master
            i2c_clk                 : inout std_logic;
            -- separated in / out
            i2c_clk_ctrl            : out   std_ulogic;
            i2c_clk_in              : in    std_ulogic;
            i2c_clk_out             : out   std_ulogic;
            -- inout
            i2c_dat                 : inout std_logic;
            -- separated in / out
            i2c_dat_ctrl            : out   std_ulogic;
            i2c_dat_in              : in    std_ulogic;
            i2c_dat_out             : out   std_ulogic;
            -- interface
            busy                    : out   std_ulogic;
            cs                      : in    std_ulogic;
            mode                    : in    std_ulogic_vector(1 downto 0);  -- 00: only read; 01: only write; 10: first read, second write; 11: first write, second read
            slave_addr              : in    std_ulogic_vector(GW_SLAVE_ADDR-1 downto 0);
            bytes_tx                : in    unsigned(to_log2(GV_MAX_BYTES+1)-1 downto 0);
            bytes_rx                : in    unsigned(to_log2(GV_MAX_BYTES+1)-1 downto 0);
            tx_data                 : in    std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
            tx_data_valid           : in    std_ulogic;
            rx_data                 : out   std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
            rx_data_valid           : out   std_ulogic;
            rx_data_en              : in    std_ulogic;
            error                   : out   std_ulogic
        );
    end component i2c_master;

begin
    reset_n <= not(reset);
    -- i2c master
    i2c_master_inst : i2c_master
        generic map (
            GV_SYS_CLOCK_RATE       => CV_SYS_CLOCK_RATE,
            GV_I2C_CLOCK_RATE       => 400000,
            GW_SLAVE_ADDR           => 7,
            GV_MAX_BYTES            => 16,
            GB_USE_INOUT            => true,
            GB_TIMEOUT              => false
        )
        port map (
            clock                   => clock,
            reset_n                 => reset_n,
            i2c_clk                 => i2c_sclk,
            i2c_clk_ctrl            => open,
            i2c_clk_in              => '0',
            i2c_clk_out             => open,
            i2c_dat                 => i2c_sdat,
            i2c_dat_ctrl            => open,
            i2c_dat_in              => '0',
            i2c_dat_out             => open,
            busy                    => i2c_busy,
            cs                      => i2c_cs,
            mode                    => i2c_mode,
            slave_addr              => i2c_slave_addr,
            bytes_tx                => i2c_bytes_tx,
            bytes_rx                => i2c_bytes_rx,
            tx_data                 => i2c_tx_data,
            tx_data_valid           => i2c_tx_data_valid,
            rx_data                 => i2c_rx_data,
            rx_data_valid           => i2c_rx_data_valid,
            rx_data_en              => i2c_rx_data_en,
            error                   => i2c_error                    
        );

    -- GPIO (0) = i2c_clk
    --GPIO (1) = i2c_dat
    -- 8mA on each GPIO Pins
    process(clock, reset)
    begin
        -- asynchronous reset
        if reset = '1' then


            state   <= S_INIT;


        elsif rising_edge(clock) then



            state   <= state_nxt;


        end if;
    end process;


    process(state,clock,reset)
    begin
    case state is
            -- Initial start state
            when S_INIT =>
                if key(0) = '1' then

                i2c_mode <= "11" ;
                i2c_slave_addr <= "1101001";


                i2c_sclk <= '1';
                i2c_sdat <= '1';


                    -- next state
                    state_nxt <= I2C_CON;
                end if;

            when I2C_CON =>



                i2c_sdat <= '0';
                i2c_rx_data <= "1000100";

                if i2c_rx_data_valid = '1' then
                    state_nxt <= I2C_READ;

                else
                    state_nxt <= I2C_CON;

                end if;

            when I2C_READ =>

                gyro <= i2c_tx_data;




            when S_WAIT_TIME =>

                    state_nxt <= S_WAIT_TIME;









    end case;

    end process;



    -- default assignments for unused signals
    gp_ctrl             <= (others => '0');
    gp_out              <= (others => '0');
    led_green           <= (others => '0');
    led_red             <= (others => '0');
    sevenseg_cs         <= '0';
    sevenseg_wr         <= '0';
    sevenseg_addr       <= (others => '0');
    sevenseg_dout       <= (others => '0');
    adc_dac_cs          <= '0';
    adc_dac_wr          <= '0';
    adc_dac_addr        <= (others => '0');
    adc_dac_dout        <= (others => '0');
    audio_cs            <= '0';
    audio_wr            <= '0';
    audio_addr          <= (others => '0');
    audio_dout          <= (others => '0');
    audio_ack_left      <= '0';
    audio_ack_right     <= '0';
    ir_cs               <= '0';
    ir_wr               <= '0';
    ir_addr             <= (others => '0');
    ir_dout             <= (others => '0');
    ir_ack_rx           <= '0';
    lcd_cs              <= '0';
    lcd_wr              <= '0';
    lcd_addr            <= (others => '0');
    lcd_dout            <= (others => '0');
    lcd_ack_rdy         <= '0';
    sram_cs             <= '0';
    sram_wr             <= '0';
    sram_addr           <= (others => '0');
    sram_dout           <= (others => '0');
    uart_cs             <= '0';
    uart_wr             <= '0';
    uart_addr           <= (others => '0');
    uart_dout           <= (others => '0');
    uart_ack_rx         <= '0';
    uart_ack_tx         <= '0';

end rtl;
```

Comment: You are driving `i2c_rxdata` from more than one signal source. That's what's wrong, exactly as the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you mixed up rx and tx.
rx_data is an output of i2c_master.

i2c_master_inst connects rx_data to i2c_rx_data. So i2c_master_inst drives i2c_rx_data.

Unnamed process "process(state,clock,reset)" contains the following statement:
i2c_rx_data <= "1000100". Which also drives i2c_rx_data. That comes down to a short circuit and luckily the HDL tools warn you about that.

You will run into other problems with this code however: process(state,clock,reset) only reevaluates its signals when state, clock or reset changed, in simulation that is. As e.g. clock is referred to in that process, the hardware will not show the same behavior. In simulation you will notice that if any other signal changes, this will not be reflected in the signals driven by this process until either state,clock or reset change value.